# after second time button click event javascript function is not working in asp.net with c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

my issues is that when I click button at that time javascript function want to call. This one is working also but for the first time only after the second time the I can't call the javascript function. I dont know where it is problem?

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#submit_mail").click(function() {
    validateform();
  });
});

function validateform() {
  var email = $('#txt_emailID').val();
  if (email == null || email == "") {
    alert("Email Should Be Complusory");
    return false;
  }
  var atposition = email.indexOf("@");
  var dotposition = email.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atposition < 1 || dotposition < atposition + 2 || dotposition + 2 >= email.length) {
    alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address...!!!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="submit_mail" value="Send" />
```

Comment: have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: yes I have check there is no error.

Comment: try using event delegation `$(document).on("click","#submit_mail",function () {
            validateform();
        });`

Comment: Yes it is working. Thank you @PrashantShirke. :)

Comment: when you submit the form it refreshes the page, I guess you have partial reload that's why your button doesn't click other time as script only run once on page load. by attaching event to document and not specific to submit button would work like charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using event delegation `$(document).on("click","#submit_mail",function () { validateform(); });`

Using event delegation you can attach event for dynamic elements (which are getting created in runtime).

I suspect your button is getting created again after ajax call due to which it is loosing its event.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need to bind the click event in the `validateform()` function.

Please try below snippet.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#submit_mail").click(function () {
            validateform();
        });
    });

function validateform() {
    var email = $('#txt_emailID').val();
    if (email == null || email == "") {
        alert("Email Should Be Complusory");
        return false;
    }
    var atposition = email.indexOf("@");
    var dotposition = email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atposition < 1 || dotposition < atposition + 2 || dotposition + 2 >= email.length) {
        alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address...!!!");
        $("#submit_mail").unbind();
        $("#submit_mail" ).bind( "click", function() {
          validateform();
        });
        return false;            
    }
    $("#submit_mail").unbind();
    $("#submit_mail" ).bind( "click", function() {
      validateform();
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: no Mayank Bhai solution not get the same thing is happing.

Comment: can you share your HTML as well?you should not having 2 same id.

Comment: sorry cant share the html but the submit mail is one id only and when i click that button it is call the validateform also but at the second time it validateform is not been call so for that I want to refresh the page and then after I want to forward the step. So for my thinking if there is 2 same id is having then at the first time only it should not be work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:

```
<script>

            function validateform() {
                var email = $('#txt_emailID').val();
                if (email == null || email == "") {
                    alert("Email Should Be Complusory");
                    return false;
                }
                var atposition = email.indexOf("@");
                var dotposition = email.lastIndexOf(".");
                if (atposition < 1 || dotposition < atposition + 2 || dotposition + 2 >= email.length) {
                    alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address...!!!");
                    return false;
                }
            }

    </script>
    <form action="http://example.com/yourpagetoprocess" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateform()">
       <input type="submit" id="submit_mail" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is you code is working. Please change if any thing wrong:

```js
            $(function () {
                $("#submit_mail").click(function () {
                    validateform();
                });
            });

        function validateform() {
            var email = $('#txt_emailID').val();
            if (email == null || email == "") {
                alert("Email Should Be Complusory");
                return false;
            }
            var atposition = email.indexOf("@");
            var dotposition = email.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (atposition < 1 || dotposition < atposition + 2 || dotposition + 2 >= email.length) {
                alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address...!!!");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt_emailID" value="" />
<input type="submit" id="submit_mail" value="Send" />
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#submit_mail").click(function() {
    validateform();
  });

  $("#submit_mail_1").click(function() {
    validateform();
  });

  $("#submit_mail_2").click(function() {
    validateform();
  });
});

function validateform() {
  var email = $('#txt_emailID').val();
  if (email == null || email == "") {
    alert("Email Should Be Complusory");
    return false;
  }
  var atposition = email.indexOf("@");
  var dotposition = email.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atposition < 1 || dotposition < atposition + 2 || dotposition + 2 >= email.length) {
    alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address...!!!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="submit_mail" value="Send" />
<input type="submit" id="submit_mail_1" value="Send" />
<input type="submit" id="submit_mail_2" value="Send" />
```

Comment: sorry i didnt understand your answer I just want only one button and regarding it the javascript function want to call. Why you are create two more button?